# android.permission.CAMERA error when publishing app on play store

Tags: react-native, expo, publish

When publishing my app (using react native expo) on play store I got this error

**APK or Android App Bundle must use authorizations that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA).**

But.... nothing that I have on my app requires camera!

Comment: just add that you are using camera in your privacy policy and in long description.

Comment: Expo uses both Google's SDK and Facebook's SDK built in. It could be something inside of these respective SDKs is triggering this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you read the message carefully you will see that you are using the permissions like camera and you don't supply a privacy policy. you need to supply a privacy policy if you do that. you can find more information about android privacy policy on google, for example here's the first link that came up in my search: https://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/